# How to turn tibble with comma a delimited column into tidy form

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following tibble:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Sample_name, ~CRT,      ~SR,      ~`Bcells,DendriticCells,Macrophage`,
  "S1",          0.079,  0.592,      "0.077,0.483,0.555",
  "S2",          0.082,  0.549,      "0.075,0.268,0.120"
)

df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Sample_name   CRT    SR `Bcells,DendriticCells,Macrophage`
#>         <chr> <dbl> <dbl>                              <chr>
#> 1          S1 0.079 0.592                  0.077,0.483,0.555
#> 2          S2 0.082 0.549                  0.075,0.268,0.120
```

Notice that the third column in comma separated. How can transform `df` into this tidy form:

```r
Sample_name CRT   SR       Score     Celltype
S1          0.079 0.592    0.077     Bcells 
S1          0.079 0.592    0.483     DendriticCells
S1          0.079 0.592    0.555     Macrophage
S2          0.082 0.549    0.075     Bcells
S2          0.082 0.549    0.268     DendriticCells
S2          0.082 0.549    0.120     Macrophage
```

Comment: This looks like the CSV just wasn't read in properly. Instead of trying to fix it after the fact, it would be easier to figure out why it wasn't in the first place.

Comment: To fix the reading, maybe `cbind(df[-4], read.csv(text = paste(names(df)[4], paste(df[[4]], collapse = '\n'), sep = '\n'), header = TRUE))`, upon which you can then easily use `tidyr::gather` to reshape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `separate`:

```
df %>%
    separate(col = `Bcells,DendriticCells,Macrophage`,
             into = strsplit('Bcells,DendriticCells,Macrophage', ',')[[1]],
             sep = ',') %>%
    gather(Celltype, score, Bcells:Macrophage)
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   Sample_name   CRT    SR       Celltype score
# <chr> <dbl> <dbl>          <chr> <chr>
# 1          S1 0.079 0.592         Bcells 0.077
# 2          S2 0.082 0.549         Bcells 0.075
# 3          S1 0.079 0.592 DendriticCells 0.483
# 4          S2 0.082 0.549 DendriticCells 0.268
# 5          S1 0.079 0.592     Macrophage 0.555
# 6          S2 0.082 0.549     Macrophage 0.120
```

without hardcoding:

```
cn <- colnames(df)[ncol(df)]
df %>%
    separate_(col = cn, into = strsplit(cn, ',')[[1]],  sep = ',') %>%
    gather_('Celltype', 'score', strsplit(cn, ',')[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way not to hard code ``Bcells,DendriticCells,Macrophage``? For example using `colnames(df)[ncol(df)]` in your code? As well as `Bcells:Macrophage` in `gather` because the number of cell types can be more than 3 and it can be named anything.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we could use `extract` from `tidyr`

```r
library(tidyverse)

vars <- unlist(strsplit(names(df)[which(str_detect(toupper(names(df)),'BCELLS'))],','))

                                                   
df %>% 
tidyr::extract(`Bcells,DendriticCells,Macrophage`, into = all_of(vars), regex = '(.*)\\,(.*)\\,(.*)') %>% 
  pivot_longer(all_of(vars), names_to = 'Celltype', values_to = 'Score')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Sample_name   CRT    SR Celltype       Score
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>          <chr>
1 S1          0.079 0.592 Bcells         0.077
2 S1          0.079 0.592 DendriticCells 0.483
3 S1          0.079 0.592 Macrophage     0.555
4 S2          0.082 0.549 Bcells         0.075
5 S2          0.082 0.549 DendriticCells 0.268
6 S2          0.082 0.549 Macrophage     0.120
```